# convert multiple text urls beginning in either www or http to absolute links

Tags: php, regex, url, replace

There are many similar questions, but I've tried about 15 different preg_match examples and none are working fully.

I have a lot of user submitted content and much of it has urls.. sometimes in the form http://www.site.com/page and sometimes like www.site.com and quite often contained in parentheses (www.site.com/page.html).

I have had no luck finding a pattern that will parse a string and convert all those to absolute html links. Wondering if anyone can help me. I found a few regex finding expressions that seemed like they would work, but I do not know how to properly convert to absolute html link when some are with the http and some without...

Here are a few expressions that I have tried:

```
function makeLinks($text) {  
    $text = preg_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
        '(<a href="\\1">\\1</a>)', $text);  
    $text = preg_replace('(www\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]\.[^ ]+)',
        '(<a href="\\1">\\1</a>)', $text);  

        return $text;
}

function makeLinks($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('~(?:www|http://)\S+~', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $text);

        return $text;
}

function makeLinks($text) {
    $text = preg_replace( '@(?<![.*">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|[a-z]\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', '<a href="\0" target="_blank">\0</a>', $text );

        return $text;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but maybe some sample codes would help explain what you are tryna achieve. Like your previous codes you said you tried out.

Comment: Urls beginning with www or http ARE absolute links.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Now, it's possible that addresses without http:// might not be interpreted correctly (by ancient / broken browsers), but regardless, those are both absolute links, and the regex to add "http://" would be a pittance.  Again, I don't understand your problem.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Or maybe you want to remove the domain name + protocol from your URL

Comment: if i put <a href="www.site.com">, chrome at least interprets it as a relative path.  I will add some of the preg functions I've tried to the question...

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex solution?

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki.. it doesn't have to be regex.. but that's the method that came up when i was trying to search for a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this string which seems to be performing well on all necessary cases:

```
function makeLinks($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('%(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-^Z0-9@:\%_\+.~#?&//=]+)%i',
    '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('%([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:\%_\+.~#?&//=]+)%i',
    '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);

        return $text;
}
```

Comment: You have to add ! and , in your regex and add [s]? in the first preg for https :

`$text = preg_replace('%(((f|ht){1}tp[s]?://)[-a-zA-^Z0-9@:\%_\+.,!~#?&//=]+)%i','<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);

$text = preg_replace('%([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:\%_\+.,!~#?&//=]+)%i','\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);`
As there are , and ! in some URLs (like metronews.fr for example)

Comment: And I had to add ) and ( in the regex too.

Answer (score 0):

This was a good start:

```
function makeLinks($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('~(?:www|http://)\S+~', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

$0 is the full match. If you group just the section without `http://` or `www.` or `http://www.`, you can concatenate that to the front.

Try this if you are still looking for an answer:

```
function makeLinks($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('~(?:http://|)(?:www\.|)(\S+)~', '<a href="http://www.$1">$0</a>', $text);
    return $text
}
```

Comment: that didn't work for me... it turned every word into a hyperlink

Comment: Oh sorry try `~\b(?:http://www.|http://(?!www.)|(?<!http://)www.)(?:\.|)(\S+)\b~`

Comment: I am not getting expected result. Please use the proper variables inside functional flow. ex: ($tect, $text, $test) used to indicate single variable.

Comment: @Navane Oops sorry that is a typo. I am going to fix it for anyone looking at this page but there is already an accepted answer.